# VBA create a nested dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary

I have the following set of code

```
Dim dic As Dictionary
Dim dataArray() As Variant
Dim headerRow(1 To 4) As Variant
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim loopCounter As Long
Dim endRow As Long
Dim endColumn As Long
Dim keyColumn As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim wsName2 As String
Dim duplicateDictionary As Dictionary

wsName2 = ActiveSheet.Name
Set duplicateDictionary = New Dictionary

Set dic = New Dictionary

With Worksheets(wsName2).Range("A1",Worksheets(wsName2).Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    keyColumn = 1
    endColumn = 4
    endRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    dataArray = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(endRow, endColumn)).Value
End With

For x = 1 To endColumn
    headerRow(x) = dataArray(1, x)
Next x

For loopCounter = 2 To endRow
    Dim storeKey As Variant
    Dim lineArray()
    Dim itemNumber As String
    Dim itemNumberAndDescription As String
    Dim q As Variant

    ReDim lineArray(1 To endColumn)

    For x = 1 To endColumn
        lineArray(x) = dataArray(loopCounter, x)
    Next x

    storeKey = lineArray(keyColumn)

    If Not dic.Exists(storeKey) Then
        dic.Add storeKey, New Collection
    End If

    'create duplicate dictionary if doesn't exist
    If Not duplicateDictionary.Exists(storeKey) Then
        duplicateDictionary.Add storeKey, New Dictionary
    End If

    dic(storeKey).Add lineArray

    itemNumber = UCase(Trim(Left(lineArray(2), InStr(1, lineArray(2), " -", vbBinaryCompare))))

    'add item in the duplicate dictionary based on the storekey
    duplicateDictionary(storeKey).Add itemNumber, itemNumber
Next loopCounter
```

What i'm trying to do, using the list below as an example, is to create a nested dictionary and each with their own key. The purpose for this is because I have a report that will checks the dictionary created above for duplicate item before adding to it.

City---Team

LA  ----Lakers

CHI ----Bulls

NY  ----Knicks

DAL ----Mavericks

BOS ----Celtics

I am able to create the first dictionary(city), but I can't seem to created a second (nested) dictionary for the team name based on the city. Help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking if it is possible to create a dictionary whose values themselves are dictionaries? In your example -- is "BOS" a key for the big dictionary and is there some sort of `Celtics` dictionary that is supposed to be the value that goes with the value "BOS"?

Comment: My question what would the code be to create a nested dictionary. Based on my table, 'BOS' would be a key that would have 'celtics' along some other items. My end goal is, I have another report that would add to the city dictionary based on the key, but only adds non duplicate name. In this case it would see that 'celtics' is already in the dictionary associated to 'BOS' and wouldn't add another one. Same goes for the other cities.

Answer (score 11):

First create -- then add the new dictionary to the outer dict. The following sub should give you some idea:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim DOD As New Dictionary
    Dim InnerDict As Dictionary

    'create one inner dictionary
    Set InnerDict = New Dictionary
    InnerDict.Add "A", 1
    InnerDict.Add "B", 2
    'add it to the dictionary of dictionaries
    DOD.Add "dict1", InnerDict

    'create another inner dictionary
    Set InnerDict = New Dictionary
    InnerDict.Add "A", 3
    InnerDict.Add "B", 4
    InnerDict.Add "C", 5
    'add it to DOD
    DOD.Add "dict2", InnerDict

    'access like:
    Debug.Print DOD("dict1")("A") 'prints 1
    Debug.Print DOD("dict2")("A") 'prints 3

    'can add new keys to inner dicts:
    DOD("dict1").Add "C", 10
    Debug.Print DOD("dict1")("C") 'prints 10

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it much easy to create the sub dictionary first and add that to the main dictionary. In this I have the "paydownDictionary" as the main one and I'm adding the sub dictionary to that with two values. So if you were to apply it to yours what You would do is get the list of teams per city and say for example:

sub dictionary. add Clippers, established 19??

sub dictionary. add Lakers, established 19??

if the city changes

add the sub dictionary to the dictionary
then create a new sub dictionary to for the next set. My code looks like - edited to look more like your code

```
Option Explicit
Public CityDictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary

Sub theDictionary()

Dim wsName2 As String
Dim payDownDictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary 'set in public
Dim subDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary

wsName2 = ActiveSheet.Name
'keyColumn = city ' column A
'secondColumn = team 'column B

lastColumn = Sheets(wsName2).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
lastRow = Sheets(wsName2).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
previousCell = ""

For Each cell In xlfile.Sheets(wsName2).range(Sheets(wsName2).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(wsName2).Cells(lastRow, 1)) 'this is your key column

    If cell.Value <> "" Then

        If previousCell = "" Then 'it's the first item
        'get the first item and add it to the subdictionary
            Set subDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary
            subDictionary.Add cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, cell.Offset(0, 2).Value 'offest 1 would be team, offset 2 is date established

        ElseIf cell.Value = previousCell Then 'we already have this cell value in the dictionary
            subDictionary.Add cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, cell.Offset(0, 2).Value

        Else ' new cell value for the dictionary
            'previousCell is your primaryKey Column
            CityDictionary.Add previousCell, subDictionary ' add the sub dictionary to the pay Down Dictionary

            Set subDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary
            subDictionary.Add cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, cell.Offset(0, 2).Value

        End If
        previousCell = cell.Value
    End If
Next
```

I feel like If you want to go this route it might be cleaner than your method.

I have about from 15-200 in each subdictionary as I was capturing rates for bonds to maturity. So this way is great for me, with max 3? teams in a city for the NBA, it might not be as efficient as other methods.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. if you need me to adjust it to be more like you reader for the worksheets I can. so if you get stuck let me know

Comment: Hi James, if you are able to adjust to be more like the worksheet, it would definitely be of great help to try and adapt it to mine. :)

Comment: Hi Tim, I've adjusted it a bit so that you're using column 1 as the key -that is city I guess. then I'm capturing 2 other columns the first one would be Team but you could get as many as you like.