# vba nested dictionary, add if item does not exist

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to parse Json files which can look something like this:

```
{
  "ModifyValues": [
    {
      "columnHeaderInput": "CH4 M (NG IN), L/MIN",
      "y1Raw": "1",
      "y1Calibrated": "2",
      "y2Raw": "2",
      "y2Calibrated": "3",
      "scale": 1,
      "unit": "L/min",
      "negativeValues": false
    },
    {
      "columnHeaderInput": "CH2 M (NG IN), L/MIN",
      "y1Raw": 1.55,
      "y1Calibrated": 1.5,
      "y2Raw": 0.67,
      "y2Calibrated": 0.6,
      "scale": 1,
      "unit": "L/min",
      "negativeValues": false
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that I would like to add a new item to the list if it does not exist, or update the existing one, or add items to it if it exist. The problem is that the user might have an empty JSON file, or just:

```
{
  "ModifyValues": [
 ]
}
```

So if it does not exist then I need to add it, here is my code saved in the settingExcel module:

```
Public JSON as Scripting.Dictionary

Public Function getCollectionInJsonFile(mainItem As String, subItem As String, value As String) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim col As Collection
    'First we check if we have mainItem
    If settingsExcel.JSON Is Nothing Then
        Set settingsExcel.JSON = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        settingsExcel.JSON.RemoveAll
    End If

    ' check if we have collection....
    If settingsExcel.JSON.Exists(mainItem) Then

        Set col = settingsExcel.JSON(mainItem)
        'Second we check if we have subItem
        If col.count > 0 Then
            'check if the item exist in the collection
            Dim i As Integer
            i = getJsonIndex(value)
            If i >= 0 Then
                Set getCollectionInJsonFile = settingsExcel.JSON(mainItem)(i)
            Else
                dict.Add subItem, value
                settingsExcel.JSON(mainItem).Add dict
                Set getCollectionInJsonFile = dict
            End If
        End If

    Else
        Set col = New Collection
        Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        dict.Add subItem, value
        col.Add dict
        settingsExcel.JSON.Add mainItem, col
        Set settingsExcel.JSON(mainItem) = dict
        Set getCollectionInJsonFile = dict

    End If

End Function


Public Sub test()
    ' Erase the dictionary
    Set settingsExcel.JSON = Nothing
'Call readConfig("C:\Users\kim\Desktop\config2.json") 'Coomment out to test for no input file
    Dim temp As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set temp = getCollectionInJsonFile("ModifyValues", "columnHeaderInput", "CH4")

End Sub
```

However i keep getting errors, saying object required:

```
Set col = settingsExcel.JSON(mainItem)
```

this seems to create an item in the dictionary!!
    settingsExcel.JSON.Exists(mainItem)
which makes the above fails.

Comment: Is JSON a member of the settingsExcel object? [This was the first hit I found on working with nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318149/4497791), I am sure you can find better resources with a bit of googling.

Comment: The module is called settingsExcel and the JSON is declared at top

Comment: Not sure if this helps but, but there's already a great JSON module for VBA. See https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON. I've used this for a number of projects, and it works for me.