# How to compare two rows of data accounting for wildcard?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I want to compare two set of rows, data from sheet "Calculated Structure" is compared against data from sheet "MAP" and if it is a match return the value in last column.

Based on other responses I have the following code which joins the rows into a string and then leverages dictionary to perform the compare. I am using dictionary to improve performance as I am comparing MAP and DATA that are both 50,000+ records.

```vb
Sub CheckRows()

Dim cl As Range
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Vlu As String
Dim VluD As String
Dim Lc As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ArrRslt() As Variant
Dim iRw As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RngTrgt As Range
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Set Ws1 = Sheets("Calculated Structure")
Set Ws2 = Sheets("Map")
Lc = Ws2.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1

RsltCol = Ws1.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

For icntr = RsltCol To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(1, icntr).value = "Calced Result" Then
        Columns(icntr).Delete
    End If
Next

LastCol = Ws1.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Cells(1, LastCol + 1).value = "Calced Result"

i = 1
x = 1
ReDim ArrRslt(0)
  
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = 1
    For Each cl In Ws2.Range("A1", Ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Vlu = Join(Application.Index(cl.RESIZE(, Lc).value, 1, 0), "|")
        dict.Add key:=Vlu, Item:=(Ws2.Cells(i, Lc + 1))
        i = i + 1
    Next cl
   
    For Each cl In Ws1.Range("B2", Ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        VluD = Join(Application.Index(cl.RESIZE(, Lc).value, 1, 0), "|")
        If dict.Exists(VluD) Then 
            CResult = dict(VluD)
            ArrRslt(x - 1) = CResult
        Else
            ArrRslt(x - 1) = "?"
        End If
        ReDim Preserve ArrRslt(0 To x)
        x = x + 1
    Next cl
End With

LastRow = Ws1.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Set RngTrgt = Ws1.Range(Cells(2, Lc + 2), Cells(LastRow, Lc + 2))
RngTrgt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrRslt)

MsgBox "Mapping Complete!"

End Sub
```

Some instances row on "MAP" have wildcard("*") designated as the cell value.

For example MAP looks like:

| Check 1 | Check 2 | Check 3 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | 123 | R1 |
| ABC | * | 123 | R2 |

And my data looks like:

| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | 123 | R1 |
| ABC | GHI | 123 | **R2** |

For my second row of data I expect to return "R2" because in the MAP check 2 is wildcarded, so any value for Field 2 should pass. Instead the "?" is returned indicating no match found. My understanding is that this is because string "ABC|GHI|123" is not defined in the map.

What can I do to account for the wildcard values?

I feel I need to evaluate each "Check/Field" individually. Meaning first see if match found for Check 1, if so search for match for Check 2, so on till all matches are found.

Comment: Hi Folks, any guidance you can provide for the problem above is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Folks, I think I can use nested dictionaries for my problem. Found this example of nested dictionary - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318290 posted by @jamesC

Though I need help modifying that code, because in my case the number of columns can vary. So how do I make number of sub-dictionaries dynamic based on number of columns?

Comment: @JohnColeman - I think I can leverage your response - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318149 - for my situation. I just need to figure out how to make number of sub-dictionaries dynamic, based on number of columns. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I tried nested dictionaries. I believe that I am able to assign values appropriate but hitting a Run-time Error '450' when trying to retrieve information from the dictionaries. Here is my code:

```
Sub theDictionary()
   Dim cl As Range
   Dim WsRslt As Worksheet
   Dim WsMap As Worksheet
   Dim Vlu As String
   Dim VluD As String
   Dim Lc As Long
   Dim MapVl As Long
   Dim RsltCol As Long
   Dim icntr As Long
   Dim LastCol As Long
   Dim rCount As Long
   Dim mCount As Long
   Dim x As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim dictCount As Long
   Dim ArrRslt() As Variant
   Dim iRw As Long
   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim previousCell As String
   Dim cResult As String
   Dim RngTrgt As Range
   Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
   Dim subDict() As Object

   Set WsRslt = Sheets("Calculated Structure")
   Set WsMap = Sheets("Map")
   MapVl = WsMap.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Lc = MapVl - 1
   
   MsgBox "Map value=" & MapVl & "and LC=" & Lc
   
   RsltCol = WsRslt.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
   
   For icntr = RsltCol To 1 Step -1
       If Cells(1, icntr).value = "Calced Result" Then
           Columns(icntr).Delete
       End If
   Next
   
   
   LastCol = WsRslt.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
   
   Cells(1, LastCol + 1).value = "Calced Result"
   
   i = 1
   x = 1
   dictCount = 1
   rCount = 1
   ReDim ArrRslt(0)
   previousCell = ""
     
ReDim subDict(1 To MapVl - 1)
For dictCount = 1 To MapVl - 1
    Set subDict(dictCount) = New Scripting.Dictionary
    subDict(dictCount).CompareMode = vbTextCompare
Next dictCount

    For Each cl In WsMap.Range("A2", WsMap.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        For rCount = 1 To MapVl - 1
                    'get the first item and add it to the subdictionary
'            MsgBox "MapVl=" & MapVl & " and rCount=" & rCount
            If rCount = 1 Then
                If subDict(rCount).Exists(cl.Offset(0, MapVl - (rCount + 1)).Value2) Then
'                    MsgBox cl.Offset(0, MapVl - (rCount + 1)) & " Exists"
                Else
'                    MsgBox cl.Offset(0, MapVl - (rCount + 1)) & " First Add"
                    subDict(rCount).Add CStr(cl.Offset(0, MapVl - (rCount + 1)).Value2), CStr(cl.Offset(0, MapVl - rCount).Value2)
                End If
            ElseIf rCount < MapVl Then
                subDict(rCount).Add CStr(cl.Offset(0, MapVl - (rCount + 1)).Value2), subDict(rCount - 1)
            End If
'                    MsgBox "Prev Cell Blank=" & previousCell & "cl.value=" & cl.value
        Next rCount
        rCount = 1
    Next cl
      
    For Each cl In WsRslt.Range("B2", WsRslt.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
       For mCount = 1 To MapVl - 1
         VluD = cl.Value2 'Join(Application.Index(cl.RESIZE(, Lc).value, 1, 0), "|")
         MsgBox "Cell Value=" & VluD
         
         If subDict(MapVl - mCount).Exists(VluD) Then
            MsgBox "VluD= " & VluD
            cResult = subDict(MapVl - mCount).Item(VluD) '<-- Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
            
            ArrRslt(x - 1) = cResult
            MsgBox "cResult=" & cResult
         Else
            ArrRslt(x - 1) = "?"
         End If
         ReDim Preserve ArrRslt(0 To x)
         x = x + 1
         Next mCount
      Next cl

   LastRow = WsRslt.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Set RngTrgt = WsRslt.Range(Cells(2, Lc + 2), Cells(LastRow, Lc + 2))
RngTrgt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrRslt)

MsgBox "Mapping Complete!"

End Sub
```

Once I am able to read the values, I still need to figure out how I am going to account for the "wildcard" values in MAP.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.